# IdentityServer 4 connect MVC5 as à client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

How should I configure MVC 5 to connect to IdentityServer4 is there any example for that?
Can't seem to get it to work.

Regards,
John

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly the same as you would connect an ASP.NET MVC 5 client to Identity Server 3. You integrate with Identity Server at the protocol level, there are no implementation specifics, so what integrates with Identity Server 3 can integrate with Identity Server 4.

Check out the Identity Server 3 samples repository which all use the .NET Framework (not Core): https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients

There are 5 example MVC 5 clients in that repository.

Comment: For the user who downvoted, don't worry the above is still true. Check out the CrossVersionIntegrationTests repository on GitHub to test IdentityServer 3 and 4 compatibility (https://github.com/IdentityServer/CrossVersionIntegrationTests). Hope that helps.